# Textbooks addressing Markov decision processes in microeconomics/game theory/decision theory?

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, game-theory, decision-theory, markov-chain

I have learned about the Markov decision process (MDP) formalism in the context of machine learning. I know that micro theorists also study MDP's, and agent behaviour in this context (both single and multi-agent I think).

I am wondering if there is a good/standard textbook on MDP's from the perspective of micro theory (game theory/decision theory)?

If not, is there at least a micro theory textbook that heavily focuses on MDP's?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you learned about MDP from Reinforcement Learning since RL tries to solve MDP without parameters.

For MDP without considering Microeconomics, (Indeed MDP is a decision-making process.)

"***Markov Decision Processes: Discrete Stochastic Dynamic Programming***" by Martin Puterman

If you want an Economics based book,

"***Recursive Methods in Economic Dynamics***" by  Nancy L. Stokey and Edward C. Prescott

For multi-agent MDP, (there are not many books for this topic specifically  although some Economics books mention the topic)

"***Competitive Markov Decision Processes***" by Jerzy Filar and Koos Vrieze